# How to handle the "Subscript out of bounds" Error by different matrices length?

Tags: r, error-handling, subscript

I have a big list, containing thousands of data frames. Those data frames contain two column by multiple rows of data. I want to calculate the cosinus similarity of each data frame within the list with a for-loop, which contains some functions and the following if - else statement, where the `Error in cos[1,2]: subscript out of bounds` comes. Do you have any ideas how to fix this. I already read, that this error occurs, when the dimensions of the matrix are to small. How can I make the code adaptive to the case to case underlying systematic and size of the matrix?

```
  Pair1 <- createMatrix(inputData)

  if (is.matrix(Pair1)) {
    solution_zscore[i,2] <- cos(Pair1)[1,2]
  }
  
  else {
    solution_zscore[i,2] <- NA   
  }
```

Kind regards and many thanks in advance,

Sebastian

Comment: Does it help if you do `try(solution_zscore[i,2] <- cos(Pair1)[1,2], silent = TRUE)`? This will continue to execute even when error occurs and do not display error message (parameter `silent` is responsible to display error message or not in the console).

Comment: Maybe `tryCatch()` might be better.  You can, as error function, create a list of all of the sub data frames which were not computable with this code.